# Is there way to extract all the duplicate records based on a particular column?

Tags: unix, awk, ksh

I'm trying to extract all (only) the duplicate values from a pipe delimited file.

My data file has 800 thousands rows with multiple columns and I'm particularly interested about column 3.   So I need to get the duplicate values of column 3 and extract all the duplicate rows from that file.

I'm, however able to achieve this as shown below..

```
cat Report.txt | awk -F'|' '{print $3}' | sort | uniq -d >dup.txt
```

and I take the above in loop as shown below..

```
while read dup
do
   grep "$dup" Report.txt >>only_dup.txt
done <dup.txt
```

I've also tried the awk method

```
while read dup
do
awk -v a=$dup '$3 == a { print $0 }' Report.txt>>only_dup.txt
done <dup.txt
```

But, as I have large number of records in the file, it's taking ages to complete.  So I'm looking for an easy and quick alternative.

For example, I have data like this:

```
1|learning|Unix|Business|Requirements
2|learning|Unix|Business|Team
3|learning|Linux|Business|Requirements
4|learning|Unix|Business|Team
5|learning|Linux|Business|Requirements
6|learning|Unix|Business|Team
7|learning|Windows|Business|Requirements
8|learning|Mac|Business|Requirements
```

And my expected output which doesn't include unique records:

```
1|learning|Unix|Business|Requirements
2|learning|Unix|Business|Team
4|learning|Unix|Business|Team
6|learning|Unix|Business|Team
3|learning|Linux|Business|Requirements
5|learning|Linux|Business|Requirements
```

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for why your shell loops calling awk were so slow (and other issues with them). See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html for other issues with your shell code.

Comment: Include in your question how many unique $3 values you'd expect to have in those 800,000+ lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be what you want:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{cnt[$3]++; next} cnt[$3]>1' file file
1|learning|Unix|Business|Requirements
2|learning|Unix|Business|Team
3|learning|Linux|Business|Requirements
4|learning|Unix|Business|Team
5|learning|Linux|Business|Requirements
6|learning|Unix|Business|Team
```

or if the file's too large for all the keys ($3 values) to fit in memory (which shouldn't be a problem with just the unique $3 values from 800,000 lines):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="|" }
{ currKey = $3 }
currKey == prevKey {
    if ( !prevPrinted++ ) {
        print prevRec
    }
    print
    next
}
{
    prevKey = currKey
    prevRec = $0
    prevPrinted = 0
}

$ sort -t'|' -k3,3 file | awk -f tst.awk
3|learning|Linux|Business|Requirements
5|learning|Linux|Business|Requirements
1|learning|Unix|Business|Requirements
2|learning|Unix|Business|Team
4|learning|Unix|Business|Team
6|learning|Unix|Business|Team
```

Comment: Lol that first one. :D Might be enough, thou.

Comment: @JamesBrown yeah that should be all they need but I started out thinking the file was large as I'd no idea what a lac was so I came up with the 2nd script above first :-)!

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT2:*** As per Ed sir's suggestion fine tuned my suggestion with more meaningful names(IMO) of arrays.

```
awk '
match($0,/[^\|]*\|/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  if(!unique_check_count[val]++){
    numbered_indexed_array[++count]=val
  }
  actual_valued_array[val]=(actual_valued_array[val]?actual_valued_array[val] ORS:"")$0
  line_count_array[val]++
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(line_count_array[numbered_indexed_array[i]]>1){
      print actual_valued_array[numbered_indexed_array[i]]
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

---

Edit by Ed Morton: FWIW here's how I'd have named the variables in the above code:

```
awk '
match($0,/[^\|]*\|/) {
  key = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  if ( !numRecs[key]++ ) {
    keys[++numKeys] = key
  }
  key2recs[key] = (key in key2recs ? key2recs[key] ORS : "") $0
}
END {
  for ( keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++ ) {
    key = keys[keyNr]
    if ( numRecs[key]>1 ) {
      print key2recs[key]
    }
  }
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed Input_file with `|`delimited so changing code a bit to as follows, which deals with new Input_file(Thanks to Ed Morton sir for pointing it out).

```
awk '
match($0,/[^\|]*\|/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  if(!a[val]++){
    b[++count]=val
  }
  c[val]=(c[val]?c[val] ORS:"")$0
  d[val]++
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(d[b[i]]>1){
      print c[b[i]]
    }
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, following will give output in same sequence of in which lines are occurring in Input_file.

```
awk '
match($0,/[^ ]* /){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  if(!a[val]++){
    b[++count]=val
  }
  c[val]=(c[val]?c[val] ORS:"")$0
  d[val]++
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(d[b[i]]>1){
      print c[b[i]]
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
2 learning Unix Business Team
4 learning Unix Business Team
6 learning Unix Business Team
3 learning Linux Business Requirements
5 learning Linux Business Requirements
```

***Explanation for above code:***

```
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program here.
match($0,/[^ ]* /){                   ##Using match function of awk which matches regex till first space is coming.
  val=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)       ##Creating variable val whose value is sub-string is from starting point of RSTART+RLENGTH value to till end of line.
  if(!a[val]++){                      ##Checking condition if value of array a with index val is NULL then go further and increase its index too.
    b[++count]=val                    ##Creating array b whose index is increment value of variable count and value is val variable.
  }                                   ##Closing BLOCK for if condition of array a here.
  c[val]=(c[val]?c[val] ORS:"")$0     ##Creating array named c whose index is variable val and value is $0 along with keep concatenating its own value each time it comes here.
  d[val]++                            ##Creating array named d whose index is variable val and its value is keep increasing with 1 each time cursor comes here.
}                                     ##Closing BLOCK for match here.
END{                                  ##Starting END BLOCK section for this awk program here.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){              ##Starting for loop from i=1 to till value of count here.
    if(d[b[i]]>1){                    ##Checking if value of array d with index b[i] is greater than 1 then go inside block.
      print c[b[i]]                   ##Printing value of array c whose index is b[i].
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you sir I changed it now, not sure my page didn't refresh so I didn't know it, thank you.

Comment: If you come up with more meaningful names than a, b, c, and d for your arrays to make the code much easier to understand then I'll look it over if you still want me to.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure sir, I have changed array names(tried my best to make name meaningful) kindly do let me know in case any queries sir, cheers.

Comment: When naming variables, name them based on what they are used for, not how they're implemented. For example `numbered_indexed_array` - that tells me the given array is indexed by numbers but absolutely nothing about how it's being used. I could tell it was indexed by numbers just by a glance at the code `numbered_indexed_array[++count]=val` so that name isn't useful. Think about what that array contains and then naming it based on that would be useful.

Comment: You have a variable named `val` which tells me it's a value. OK - everything is a value so that's not useful. What kind of value is it? Looks like it's a key value used for determining uniquness so you could have named it `key` and that'd be a far more useful name than `val`. Now how about `!unique_check_count[val]++`? Looks like that'd be more useful as `!seen[key]++`. Now how about `numbered_indexed_array[++count]=val`? Well `count` isn't useful, what's it a count of? Looks like its the count of number of unique key values so that whole line would be `keys[++numKeys]=key`.

Comment: and it looks like `actual_valued_array[val]` should be something like `key2recs[key]` as it appears to be mapping keys to the associated records. And so on...

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I edited your answer to add a version of the script using IMHO more useful, meaningful variable names to demonstrate what I'm getting at. In thinking of what the arrays were used for I realized that `unique_check_count[val]++` is identical to `line_count_array[val]++` so I could get rid of one of them - that's a side benefit of coming up with meaningful names, it helps you identify ways to improve the code. There are other opportunities for improvement (e.g. consider what that ternary is doing vs the `if` above it)

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk -F\| '{                  # set delimiter
    n=$1                       # store number
    sub(/^[^|]*/,"",$0)        # remove number from string
    if($0 in a) {              # if $0 in a
        if(a[$0]==1)           # if $0 seen the second time
            print b[$0] $0     # print first instance
        print n $0             # also print current
    }
    a[$0]++                    # increase match count for $0
    b[$0]=n                    # number stored to b and only needed once
}' file
```

Output for the sample data:

```
2|learning|Unix|Business|Team
4|learning|Unix|Business|Team
3|learning|Linux|Business|Requirements
5|learning|Linux|Business|Requirements
6|learning|Unix|Business|Team
```

<s>Also, would this work:</s>

```
$ sort -k 2 file | uniq -D -f 1
```

or `-k2,5` or smth.  Nope, as the delimiter changed from space to pipe.

Comment: So the delimiter changed from space to pipe. Maybe fixin' later, gotta run.

Comment: Fixed the changed delimiter.

Comment: Cool. I too fixed delimiter after Ed sir mentioned to me, like I requested you to check my code, I requested him also :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Your variable names are too long. I'm a b, c, d guy myself. :D :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Two steps of improvement.
**First step:**
After

```
awk -F'|' '{print $3}' Report.txt | sort | uniq -d >dup.txt
# or
cut -d "|" -f3 < Report.txt | sort | uniq -d >dup.txt
```

you can use

```
grep -f <(sed 's/.*/^.*|.*|&|.*|/' dup.txt) Report.txt
# or without process substitution
sed 's/.*/^.*|.*|&|.*|/' dup.txt > dup.sed
grep -f dup.sed Report.txt
```

**Second step:**
Use `awk` as given in other, better, answers.